# Is there a *portable* way to store std::filesystem_file_time_type as an integral number?

Tags: c++, c++17, filesystems, visual-studio-2019, c++-chrono

Background is a (portable: Win+Linux) program that collects all file times of files from directories and stores them in text files as numbers.
The text files containing these numbers are read sometime later by the program and the previously stored numbers are compared with the new ones. The crucial fact is that the reading and writing programs run on different platforms and the files come from shared network drives.

How to output the time returned by std::filesystem::last_write_time() in C++17 as a integral number in an optimal and portable way?

- std::filesystem::file_time_type
- C++17
- portable
- single integral number

Above question is not a duplicate!

---

What I found so far:

```
template < typename TP >
std::time_t
to_time_tnew( TP tp )
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto sctp = time_point_cast< system_clock::duration >( tp - TP::clock::now() + system_clock::now() );
    return system_clock::to_time_t( tp );
}
```

and this:

```
template < typename TP >
std::time_t
to_time_t( TP tp )
{
    //    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto sctp = std::chrono::time_point_cast< std::chrono::system_clock::duration >( tp - TP::clock::now() + std::chrono::system_clock::now() );
    return std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t( sctp );
}
```

But these have the problem of asking 2 times "now()" with the result of jittering the outcome.

---

My current (more or less helpless) solution is as follows (Windows and Raspi with Linux):
I hate to use these constants and the #defines, but this is only prototype code.

```
#include <cstdarg>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <filesystem>
#include <chrono>

#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#ifdef WIN32
#define FILE_TIME__FILE_TIME_OFFSET ( std::filesystem::__std_fs_file_time_epoch_adjustment ) // ( 116444736000000000ull )
#define FILE_TIME__FILE_TIME_GAIN   ( 10000000ull )
#else
#define FILE_TIME__FILE_TIME_OFFSET ( 12009080074ull )
#define FILE_TIME__FILE_TIME_GAIN   ( 1000000000ull )
#endif

#ifdef WIN32
std::time_t
TimeHelper::to_time_t( const std::filesystem::file_time_type file_time ) const
{
    std::time_t                            rv = 0ull;
    const std::filesystem::file_time_type *ptr = &file_time;
    uint64_t *                             timeptr = ( uint64_t * ) ptr;
    uint64_t                               time = *timeptr;
    if ( time >= FILE_TIME__FILE_TIME_OFFSET )
    {
        time -= FILE_TIME__FILE_TIME_OFFSET;
        time += ( FILE_TIME__FILE_TIME_GAIN >> 1 ); // do correct rounding by adding halv of dividend before division
        time /= FILE_TIME__FILE_TIME_GAIN;
        rv = time;
    }
    return rv;
}
std::filesystem::file_time_type
TimeHelper::to_FileTimeType( const std::time_t time ) const
{
    uint64_t                         time_t1 = time * FILE_TIME__FILE_TIME_GAIN;      // time_t to 100ns
    uint64_t                         time_t2 = time_t1 + FILE_TIME__FILE_TIME_OFFSET; // time_t to offset 01.01.1601
    std::filesystem::file_time_type *ptr = ( std::filesystem::file_time_type * ) &time_t2;
    std::filesystem::file_time_type  rv = *ptr;

    return rv;
}
#else

std::time_t
TimeHelper::to_time_t( const std::filesystem::file_time_type file_time ) const
{
    const std::filesystem::file_time_type *ftptr = &file_time;
    const uint64_t                         ft = *( ( uint64_t * ) ftptr );
    const uint64_t                         offs = FILE_TIME__FILE_TIME_OFFSET;
    const uint64_t                         ts = ft / FILE_TIME__FILE_TIME_GAIN;
    std::time_t                            rv = 0;
    if ( offs < ts )
    {
        rv = ( std::time_t ) ( ts - offs );
    }
    return rv;
}
std::filesystem::file_time_type
TimeHelper::to_FileTimeType( const std::time_t time ) const
{
    uint64_t                        offs = FILE_TIME__FILE_TIME_OFFSET;
    uint64_t                        t1 = time + offs;
    uint64_t                        t2 = t1 * FILE_TIME__FILE_TIME_GAIN;
    std::filesystem::file_time_type ft = *( ( std::filesystem::file_time_type * ) &t2 );
    return ft;
}
#endif
```

Comment: Perhaps the [to_utc and from_utc methods](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/file_clock/to_from_utc) so that you're guaranteed to write stuff with a common epoch?

Comment: @NathanPierson But the question is specifically tagged C++17, so I assume C++20 is not available. OP, you should tag [tag:c++-chrono] as well perhaps?

Comment: None of the 2 proposed alternate answers answer the OP's question.  That sad, I will not vote to reopen , because any answer would be opinion base.  @Jesko: your best bet is a proprietary format, or even text.

Comment: I added the tag and @MichaëlRoy you are right, that none of the answers helps me with the question. Proprietary format - ok, I want to use a plain number (e.g. 64-bit, unsigned), but how to overcome the importable implementations all overall ? Do I need to go the #ifdef horror ?

Comment: This just ***screams*** [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What *problem* is "collect all file times of files from directories and store them in text files as numbers" meant to solve?

Comment: Simple problem: recognize the modification of a file-date/time across systems by only a single number.

Comment: @Jesko  Pick a format let's say, Julian time since 1/1/1970, or whichever is most simple to work with, and make conversion funcrtions from filesystem time to that format for each of your target OSes.  If you pick a format that's already supported on one or more target systems, then you'll save yourself some time.

Comment: This would mean, that the original file time is converted into this date, from that into a number and then stored. And this is the best way to do it ?

Comment: This is the only way that would guarantee that all your platforms share the same format.

Comment: @Jesko The 64-bits time_t format comes to mind.  The conversion functions are easy to find, and it can easily be modified to accommodate milliseconds without having to worry about overflows.

Comment: gcc uses 2174-01-01 00:00:00 UTC as the file_time epoch.

Comment: Goal is to get the same results with this "integral number" (here time_t format) on all systems with the result from the last_write_time() function under all OS's. In fact I don't need time_t; any other number is good too ... (a calculation back to a real date format e.g. YYYYMMDD-hhmmss would be a nice benefit, but currently(!) not needed).

Comment: I think most portable way in your case would be to have one reference file with fixed modification time(it should never change!), and you can store other modification times relatively to this reference file's time. That way you will have same number, assuming you will use same tick period, on all platforms.

Comment: OK, this is the other way around: my way was to get the same number on all systems, you propose a(?) reference file to get offset and period. However, I would say that we need two files to get both numbers (the CONSTANTS). Both files have a known difference (in seconds ?) and the time difference of the two files gives a number equal to this number. This gives the time period. The known date of one of the files combined with the number of seconds between the two files gives the difference of one day. From this you can conclude the basis of the count.